# Find the range of $f(x) = x^2$ defined on the domain $-1 \leq x \leq 4$

Tags: functions

$f(x)=x^2$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 4$

So I put everything to the power of $2$ and got:
$$1\leq x^2 \leq 16$$

However the answer should be:

$$0 \leq f(x) \leq 16$$

How can I get that?

Comment: $f(0)=0$. Is $0$ in the domain?

Comment: It should be. F(x) is bigger or equal than 0.

Comment: To produce $\leq$, type \leq in math mode; to produce $\geq$, type \geq in math mode.

Comment: "So I put everything to the power $2$". Well "everything" includes here real numbers that belong to $[0,1]$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Okay, thanks :)

Comment: @drhab Yes, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x^2$ is defined on the domain $[-1, 4]$.

As shown in the graph below, the function $f(x) = x^2$ decreases from $1$ at $x = -1$ to $0$ at $x = 0$, then increases to $16$ at $x = 4$.  The minimum value the function obtains on the interval $[-1, 4]$ is $0$ since $x^2 \geq 0$ for each real number $x$.  The maximum value it obtains is $16$ at $x = 4$.  Since the function $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous on $[-1, 4]$, it achieves every value between $0$ and $16$.  Hence, the range is $[0, 16]$.

[image: graph_of_f(x)=x^2_defined_on_[-1,4]]

Comment: Ah, alright, thank you, now I get it.

Comment: @JohnFire If you find this helpful, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It removes the question from the "Unanswered" queue (It also gives you +2 repuation). I strongly recommend that you do this for your other questions too.

Comment: @projectilemotion ahh, didn't know I can do that thanks :) and done

Answer (score 2):

Be careful,
$$-1\leq x\leq 4\nRightarrow f(-1)\leq f(x)\leq f(4).$$

This statement is true only if $f$ is injective (and increasing). In you case, $x\longmapsto x^2$ is not injective on $-1\leq x\leq 4$, that's why your argument doesn't work. But $x\longmapsto x^2$ is injective on $[-1,0]$ and on $[0,4]$. Therefore, 
$$-1\leq x\leq 0\underset{f\ decreasing}{\implies} 0\leq f(x)\leq 1$$
and $$0\leq x\leq 4\underset{f\ increasing}{\implies} 0\leq f(x)\leq 16.$$
To conclude,
$$-1\leq x\leq 0\implies f(x)\in [0,16]\cup [0,1]=[0,16].$$